# What indentation is required for a case statement within a let statement?

Tags: haskell, indentation, do-notation

Working in haskell, found odd behavior, stripped it down to bare bones

This Works

```
a :: Bool
a = case True of
    True -> True
    False -> False
```

But when I try

```
b :: IO Bool
b = do
    let b' = case True of
        True -> True
        False -> False
    return b'
```

I get

```
ghci>:l test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )

test.hs:16:14: parse error on input ‘->’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

So I try

```
c :: IO Bool
c = do
    let c' = case True of
            True -> True
            False -> False
    return c'
```

And this works.

What? Why? Why do I need an extra indent in this case? I can't find anything on this, probably because these keyword are so short and common in everyday language. Is there some spec that explains this behavior?

Comment: The indentation level of the `let` block starts at the first non-whitespace character after `let`.  So `True` is being interpreted as a clause in the `let` block; one more space will get you inside the `case` block

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have the exact wording from the spec, but this [Wikibook page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation) explains the issue quite clearly.

The reason why it works like this is simple: to support binding multiple variables via a single let-group, such as:

```
c = do
    let c' = …
        d  = …
        e  = …
    return c'
```

Your `True -> …` and `False -> …` are mistakenly interpreted as additional variables to be bound.

Comment: And here I thought the capitalization of Data constructors was meant to remove ambiguities like this. I suppose that's what I get for trying to work with python and other languages at the same time

Comment: "capitalization of Data constructors was meant to remove ambiguities like this" You can't rely on that in this case.  What if you had a pattern match like: `case … of { x -> …; _ -> …; }` ? In this case `x` and `_` are both valid variable names. (Contrived example, I know, but still.)

Comment: And the other way as well, `let Just f = ...` is a perfectly valid declaration.

Answer (score 17):

The basic indentation rules are actually quite simple:

- after the keywords which start a block (`where`,`let`,`do`,`case .. of`) note down the column where the next word starts (which might be in the next line)
- lines indented exactly as that are new entries in the block
- lines indented more than that continue the previous entry
- a line indented less than that ends the block right before that line
- in nested blocks, apply the rules to the outermost block, first

Tricky example:

```
1 + case x of
      A -> 45  -- note where "A" starts
      B -> 10  -- same indentation: another case branch
       + 2     -- more indented, so it's "10+2"
     + 10      -- less indented, so it's "1+(case ...)+10"
```

In your case,

```
let b' = case True of
    True -> True
    False -> False
```

we have two nested blocks, one for `let` and one for `case..of`. The `let` blocks uses the column of `b'`. The `case..of` block tries to reuse the same column, but we need to apply the rules the the outermost block, first. So the `True -> ...` line is actually a new entry of the `let` block. This triggers a parsing error.

Comment: As a beginner to Haskell, I do not think the indentation rules are simple, however, this is the best explanation on them I have come across.  I've bookmarked this answer and expect to keep coming back to it :)

Comment: @jrahhali If everything fails, you can postpone learning the indentation rules and use explicit braces-and-semicolons, e.g. `case x of { True -> ... ; False -> ... }` and `let { x = ... ; y = ... ; z = ... } in ...`. In such way, indentation no longer matters. This is not a common style in Haskell, since it's more noisy, but perhaps for a beginner it helps being more explicit. You can learn the exact indentation rules after you mastered the important parts of Haskell.