# How to use let or where statement within binding

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm writing `hspec` test suite which uses binding as follows:

```
it "should take the x component" $ do
    (getX $ coord $ [1,0,2]) `shouldBe` 1
```

However, for more complicated statement, one-liner is not conveniently readable so I try to strip the variable out in `where` expression:

```
it "should take the x component" $ do
    (getX c) `shouldBe` 1
       where c = coord $ [1,0,2]
```

But this turns out illegal statement in Haskell. Using `let` does not succeed either.

```
it "should take the x component" $ do
    let c = coord $ [1,0,2]
    in (getX c) `shouldBe` 1
```

How can I assign a helper variable for the same purpose as `let` or `where` within `do` binding? Exploring the documentations but can't find a good example though.

Comment: By the way, the parentheses around `getX c` are redundant. So is the `$` between `coord` and `[1,0,2]`. And `getX $ coord $ [1,0,2]` should probably be written either `getX (coord [1,0,2])` or as `getX . coord $ [1,0,2]`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually the statement was just a simplified sample for the question. My actual test statement is much more complicated for grouping so I really need either `let` or `where`.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the `let` or `where`, but about how you wrote those two expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to say why the first one fails without seeing more context. The second fails because `let` works differently in `do` blocks. Either indent the `in` another couple spaces or delete the keyword `in` and make the rest of the line align with the keyword `let`.

Comment: I haven't realised this needs extra indentation of `in` or even omitting it. Sounds a bit syntactic inconsistency to me.

Comment: @TaoP.R. It follows from the [general indentation rules](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33010779/3234959) which apply to `do`. Basically, indented in that way it means `do { let c = ... ; in getX c ... }` making `in ...` the second entry in the `do` block, apart from the first entry, which is wrong. By the way, you can also simply remove `do` here, since there's only one entry in that block, so we can not start a block at all and forget indentation.

Answer (score 4):

`let` statements inside `do` do not need the `in` keyword. In other words, try this:

```
it "should take the x component" $ do
    let c = coord $ [1,0,2]
    (getX c) `shouldBe` 1
```