# why isn't this incorrect indentation in haskell?

Tags: haskell

Why doesn't line 5 contain an indentation error. I expected to get a parse error on compilation. I expected that the `+` on line 5 would have to be aligned under the `*` in line 4.

```
module Learn where

x = 10
  * 5
 + y  -- why isn't this incorrect indentation

myResult = x * 5

y = 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It compiles because there's no block there to consider.

Indentation only matters after `where`, `let`, `do`, `case of`. 
These keywords start a block of things, and it is important to understand whether a line continues the previous entry, starts a new entry, or ends the block.

```
case f 5 of
   A -> foo
      32         -- continues the previous entry
   B -> 12       -- starts a new entry
+ bar 43         -- ends the case
```

After `=` we do not need to split a block into entries: there's only a single expression. Hence no [indentation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33010779/3234959) apply.

Answer (score 1):

This compiles because the definition of `x` was all to the right of the beginning of `x`. It's not important where each line starts as long as those lines are indented to the right of `x`.