# Why is it a syntax error to linebreak case matches without extra indentation, and what's the recommended style to get around it?

Tags: haskell, syntax, switch-statement, indentation

I just discovered that this

```
foo = case ((), ()) of
       ( ()
       , () ) -> ()
```

fails with

```
/tmp/wtmpf-file11080.hs:3:8:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

This can be made to work by indenting the second line of the pattern

```
foo = case ((), ()) of
       ( ()
        , () ) -> ()
```

but this feels inconsistent with my usual style, especially in

```
bar = case ( some lengthy :: Complicated typed expression
           , another also lengthy :: Expression with (Other types) ) of
       ( Complicated (Pattern match) to (unwrap)
       , Expression that's (Again not so short) ) -> the Rest of my Code
```

How should the above be rewritten / formatted to look most consistent?

Comment: If you just wanna minimise the line noise from a complex pattern you could wrap it up in a pattern synonym, or put the `case` expression in a higher-order function a la `maybe`/`either`/`foldr`

Answer (score 7):

By the [indentation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33010779/3234959), the code

```
foo = case ((), ()) of
       ( ()
       , () ) -> ()
```

is desugared to

```
foo = case ((), ()) of
       { ( ()
       ; , () ) -> ()
       }
```

which is a `case` with two branches, the first one being a syntax error.

I would recommend the following style instead:

```
foo = case ((), ()) of
       (( ()
        , () )) -> ()
```

or even (not extremely elegant, though)

```
foo = case ((), ()) of
       _@( ()
         , () ) -> ()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also just rewrite the pattern match as

```
   (Complicated (Pattern match) to (unwrap),
    Expression that's (Again not so short)) -> the Rest of my Code
```

I know it's incompatible with your style, but I think there is no real reason to use that style for tuples (aside from consistency).