# Indentation problems in GHCi

Tags: haskell, indentation, ghci

I'm learning Haskell and keep getting these indentation errors when I try to define functions over multiple lines in GHCi.  Here's an attempt to redefine the `elem` function:

```
λ: :{
| let elem' x xs
|     | null xs = False
|     | x == head xs = True
|     | otherwise = elem' x (tail xs)
| :}

<interactive>:15:5: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

Do the `=` signs somehow need to be aligned?

Comment: You have to indent it at least one space further so it’s “inside” the definition and not just at the same level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to indent the guards further. If you leave them at the same indentation than the `elem'` name, GHC(i) will attempt to parse them as additional definitions within the `let`-block, and not as part of the definition of `elem`:

```
let elem' x xs
        | null xs = False
        | x == head xs = True
        | otherwise = elem' x (tail xs)
```

If you are using GHC 8 or above, you don't need a `let` for defining things in GHCi, so this (between `:{` and `:}`, as before) will just work:

```
elem' x xs
    | null xs = False
    | x == head xs = True
    | otherwise = elem' x (tail xs)
```

Comment: Got it, thanks.  This seems to make coding in ghci pretty cumbersome though.  Are there any tricks or tools for making this a bit easier?

Comment: @dsaxton The indentation rules, including this one involving `let`, are the same in GHCi and elsewhere. One alternative is using explicit braces and semicolons -- while I don't think it actually improves things, it is ocasionally handy if you want to enter something relatively short as a one-liner in the prompt. What I often do instead is typing multi-line definitions in a GVim window (or some other lightweight editor) and pasting them between `:{` and `:}` in GHCi. (Also note that, if you want to golf it, the linebreaks are actually optional when using guards.)

Answer (score 0):

A `let` indented like this

```
let elem' x xs
    | null xs = False
    | x == head xs = True
    | otherwise = elem' x (tail xs)
```

is a `let` with four entries much like

```
let x1 = ...
    x2 = ...
    x3 = ...
    x4 = ...
```

if you want to continue a previous entry, rather than starting a new one, you should indent it more. The rule is the same in source files and in GHCi. The indentation rule might look a bit mysterious at the beginning but it's actually [fairly simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33010779/3234959).