# Haskell IO indentation

Tags: haskell, io, guard-statement

I tried to rewrite that program, which is working:

```
nameIOite :: IO ()
nameIOite = do
    putStrLn "What's your name ?"
    name <- getLine
    if name `elem` ["Simon","John","Phil"]
  --if name == "Simon" || name == "John" || name == "Phil" also works but is ugly.   
        then putStrLn "I think Haskell is a great programming language."
        else if name == "Koen"
            then putStrLn "I think debugging Haskell is fun."
            else putStrLn "I don't know your name."
```

This is done using if/then/else (therefore the suffix ite in `nameIOite`)

Then I'vs tried using guards:

```
nameIOg :: IO ()
nameIOg = do
    putStrLn "What's your name ?"
    name <- getLine
    let answer
        | name `elem` ["Simon","John","Phil"]   = "I think Haskell is a great programming language."
        | name == "Koen"                        = "I think debugging Haskell is fun."
        | otherwise                             = "I don't know your name."
    putStrLn answer
```

This didn't work:

```
test.hs:6:9: error:
parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
  |
6 |    | name `elem` ["Simon","John","Phil"]   = "I think Haskell is   a great programming language."
  |    ^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

After some experimenting, the solution turned out to indent the guards once more (which isn't clear to me at all):

```
nameIOg :: IO ()
nameIOg = do
    putStrLn "What's your name ?"
    name <- getLine
    let answer
            | name `elem` ["Simon","John","Phil"]   = "I think Haskell is a great programming language."
            | name == "Koen"                        = "I think debugging Haskell is fun."
            | otherwise                             = "I don't know your name."
    putStrLn answer

Ok, one module loaded.
```

**Where does that double indentation come from and is there a way to write this more elegently ?**

(By the way, I stumbled across this when reviewing my wikibook.hs files.)

Source of example: [there](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Simple_input_and_output)

Solutions:         [there](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Solutions/Simple_input_and_output)

Comment: Note also that the extra indentation can be a single space – as long as the `|`s are at least one character to the right of the `a`, this should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`let` allows multiple definitions, as in

```
main = do
   doSomething
   let x = 1
       y = 2
       z = 3
   print (x+y+z)
```

Note the indentation. `y = 2` is not parsed to continue the definition `x = 1` since it starts on the same column.

If you want a new line to be parsed as if it continued the previous line, you have to indent it more. E.g.

```
main = do
   doSomething
   let x | someCondition = 1
         | otherwise     = 0   -- more indented
       y = 2
       z = 3
   print (x+y+z)
```

or, using another line

```
main = do
   doSomething
   let x
          | someCondition = 1   -- more indented
          | otherwise     = 0   -- more indented
       y = 2
       z = 3
   print (x+y+z)
```

Indentation rules might seem puzzling at first, but they are actually
[quite simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33010779/3234959).

I think your current code is as elegant as it might be -- it looks fine to me.

If you want more alternatives, you could use `if then else`, even if most Haskellers would prefer guards. (Personally, I don't have a real preference)

```
main = do
   doSomething
   let x = if condition               then 1
           else if someOtherCondition then 0
           else                            -1
       y = 2
       z = 3
   print (x+y+z)
```

You could also use another line, e.g. (I'd tend to prefer that)

```
main = do
   doSomething
   let x =
          if condition               then 1
          else if someOtherCondition then 0
          else                            -1
       y = 2
       z = 3
   print (x+y+z)
```

or even

```
main = do
   doSomething
   let x =
          if condition
          then 1
          else if someOtherCondition
          then 0
          else -1
       y = 2
       z = 3
   print (x+y+z)
```

I'm not claiming a style is overwhelmingly better than another one.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is in-line pattern matching for sum types. This is nice if you have a short bit of code and you do not want to use multiple lines.

```hs
z <- maybeDoSomething :: IO (Maybe Int)
let x = case z of { Nothing -> 0; Just v -> v }
```

It can also short the space required for pattern matching in anonymous functions. This:

```hs
(\x -> case t of
         Nothing -> 0
         Just v  -> v
)
```

Can be changed to this:

```hs
(\x -> case t of { Nothing -> 0; Just v  -> v })
```

You can also avoid `if-then-else`.

```hs
t <- didSomethingSucceed :: IO Bool
let x = case t of { True -> 1; False -> 0 }
```

I would only use this if the lines can be kept short and you have a small number of patterns to match, otherwise it might be hard to read.