# haskell: Implementation of elementAt' function with guards for list with index from 1 to n

Tags: haskell

I'm solving some problem on https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/1_to_10.

I attempts to implements a second solution to problem 3 using guards. My goals is to wrap a guard in order to implement error manangement.

The code is this:

```
elementAt' :: [a] -> Int -> a 
elementAt' xs k = if k < 1 || k > length xs then error "IndexOutOfbound" else elem xs K
    where elem xs k
        | k == 1 = x
        | k > 1  = elem (tail xs) k
```

The error is this:

```
   parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
   |
11 |         | k == 1 = x
   |         ^
```

I tried to work with indentation, but I didn't succeed

Comment: The indentation is incorrect, you need to move it at least one space more to the right than the start of `elem`.

Comment: There was other errors, but now it works.

Comment: You might want to read a [short summary of the indentation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004521/what-indentation-is-required-for-a-case-statement-within-a-let-statement/33010779#33010779).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indentation is indeed wrong, you need to move it at least one column more to the right than the start of `elem`, so:

```
elementAt' :: [a] -> Int -> a 
elementAt' xs k = if k < 1 || k > length xs then error "IndexOutOfbound" else elem xs K
    where elem xs k
           | k == 1 = x
           | k > 1  = elem (tail xs) k
```

But this is not sufficient to make this compile. You furthermore wrote `K` instead of `k` at the definition of `elementAt' xs k = …`, furthermore `x` is not defined, so you can use `head`, finally you should decrement `k` in the recursive call:

```
elementAt' :: [a] -> Int -> a 
elementAt' xs k = if k < 1 || k > length xs then error "IndexOutOfbound" else elem xs k
    where elem xs k
           | k == 1 = head xs
           | k > 1  = elem (tail xs) (k-1)
```

Now it compiles but still it is not very idiomatic Haskell. You make use of `length` for example, which runs in *linear* time with the length of the list. If the list has infinite length, it will get stuck, furthermore you make use of `head` and `tail`, and these are non-total functions. Yes, we know that this will always work on a `cons`, since otherwise `k > length` would be triggered, but regardless it is often batter to use pattern matching over non-total functions.

Therefore a more idiomatic approach is likely:

```
elementAt' :: [a] -> Int -> a
elementAt' xs k
    | k < 1 = error "IndexOutOfBound"
    | otherwise = go xs k
    where go [] _ = error "IndexOutOfBound"
          go (x:xs) i
              | i <= 1 = x
              | otherwise = go xs (i-1)
```

Here we know that `k` is larger than the length if the list is exhausted, so in the `go []` case.

Of course indexing should start at zero, as is documented in [EWD831](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) :).

Comment: You writed this answer with all errors and idiomatic problems meanwhile I fixed my code after your comment. This is a very complete answer. Thanks a lot.