# If syntax in where blocks

Tags: haskell

Can I use if syntax in a where block? In the following, the `if` in the second where block where `second` is defined yields a parse error and I can't figure it out.

```
data Label = A | B | C deriving (Show)
type Path = ([(Label, Int)],Int)
data Section = Section { getA :: Int, getB :: Int, getC :: Int } deriving (Show)

getPath :: Section -> (Path, Path)  -> (Path, Path)
getPath () (Section a b c) = go
    where 
        go ((toppath,top),(bottompath,bottom))
            |top<c+bottom = ((A,a):toppath,top+a, second)
            |otherwise = ((A,a):(C,c):bottompath,bottom+c+a, second)
                where second =
                    if (bottom<c+top)
                        then ((B,b):bottompath,bottom+a)
                        else ((A,b):(C:c):toppath,top+c+a)
```

Comment: As an aside, `()` is not valid for either an argument of type `Section` or an argument of type `(Path, Path)`.

Comment: As a beginner I found it was generally easier to avoid indentation errors by *always* putting a newline+indent after a layout keyword (`where`, `do`, `let`, `of`) instead of having to worry about alignment at all. Here, that would just mean putting a line break between `where` and `second` and indenting accordingly. Alternatively, you can always use explicit `{}` blocks and `;` separators, but (imo unfortunately) there’s no option to make them required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but you should indent the `if` in the scope of the `where`, so:

```
getPath :: Section -> (Path, Path)  -> (Path, Path)
getPath () (Section a b c) = go
    where 
        go ((toppath,top),(bottompath,bottom))
            |top<c+bottom = ((A,a):toppath,top+a, second)
            |otherwise = ((A,a):(C,c):bottompath,bottom+c+a, second)
                where second =
                       if (bottom<c+top)  -- ← extra indentation
                        then ((B,b):bottompath,bottom+a)
                        else ((A,b):(C:c):toppath,top+c+a)
```

There are however some type errors, for example:

- `()` is the data constructor of the unit type, but not a `Section`, so you should remove `()` in `getPath () (Section a b c) = …`;
- you construct 3-tuples with `((A,a):toppath, top+a, second)`; and
- the `C` in in `(C : c)` is a `Label`, not a `Path`, so that will also error.

You will thus need to fix some problems in the code.

Comment: Thanks I hadn't noticed those yet haha. Why do I have to indent the if twice? I don't see any alignment going on.

Comment: The `if` must be more indented than the end of the `where`

Comment: @squirrels You might want to read a short [summary of the indentation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004521/what-indentation-is-required-for-a-case-statement-within-a-let-statement/33010779#33010779).

Comment: @Sir4ur0n More than that, right? It must be indented beyond the first character of the name it is defining.